# Why rename() and remove() functions don't work?

Tags: c, file, file-rename

If I use this code alone (with a main function) it works.

But when I include this function in my project, it give two files :

`annuaire_client.txt` and `annuaire1.txt`

The code used is provided below:

```
void delete_client(){
    FILE *annuaire_client,*annuaire1;
    printf("\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tNum de compte a supprimee: ");

    int delete_line;
    scanf("%d",&delete_line);

    char ch;
    int  line = 1;

    //ouvrir le fichier original
    annuaire_client = fopen("annuaire_client.txt", "r");
    ch = getc(annuaire_client);

    //retour au debut
    rewind(annuaire_client);
    //ouvrir nouveau fichier
    annuaire1 = fopen("annuaire1.txt", "w");

    while (ch != EOF)
    {
        if (ch == '\n')
        {
            line++;
        }
        //sautez la line a supprimer
        if (line != delete_line)
        {
            //copier les lines vers annuaire1.txt
            fprintf(annuaire1,"%c",ch);
        }

        ch = getc(annuaire_client);
    }

    fclose(annuaire1);
    fclose(annuaire_client);
    remove("annuaire_client.txt");
    rename("annuaire1.txt","annuaire_client.txt");
}
```

Comment: the posted code is missing a few key items: 1) `#include <stdio.h>`  2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value from `fopen()` to assure the operation was successful 3) always check  (==0) the returned value from `rename()` to assure the operation was successful. 4) always check (==0) the returned value from `remove()` to assure the operation was successful.  Any time a system function returned value indicates the function failed, call: `perror()` as that will output any enclosed text string + the error message that the OS thinks is the reason the function call failed.

Answer (score 1):

You should check the returned value of remove and rename:

```
    if (remove("annuaire_client.txt") != 0) {
        /* handle error */
    }
    if (rename("annuaire1.txt","annuaire_client.txt") == -1) {
        /* handle error */
    }
```

One of many possibilities is that you keep descriptor opened by main function while calling remove. Make sure you pair all `fopen` with `fclose` or even if you `unlink`/`remove` paths your process will still keep (deleted) descriptors open which may cause fatal errors if you reach the limit of descriptors allocated for it (`fopen` will fail - this has happened to me today, so it is not purely artificial situation). Remember also, it is undefined behavior to call `fclose` on invalid pointer, i.e. not a `FILE*`, on NULL in particular.

Comment: thank you guys 
can you rewrite the whole code for me? im a beginner and i didnt get most of ur points can you gimme the right code i must merge to my project?

Comment: @YoussefAzougagh It is possible but it won't do much good for you as you really have to understand each and single line of that. Better option for you would be to ask specific questions about things you do not understand.

Answer (score 1):

You can try check the result code for your functions.
For instance, for `rename` function you can use some code like:

```
   #include <errno.h>
```

(...)

```
   int ret;

   ret = rename("annuaire1.txt", "annuaire_client.txt");

   if(ret == 0) 
   {
      printf("File renamed successfully");
   }
   else 
   {
      printf("Error: unable to rename the file");
      fprintf(stderr, "System error (%d): %s\n", errno, strerror(errno);
   }
```

Comment: using the suggested method results in: 1) the error message is output on `stdout` rather than `stderr`  2) an additional header file must be included via `#include <errno.h>`.   Suggest using `perror()` for error messages or use: `fprintf( stderr, "formatstring\n", parameters)` of which one of those parameters should be `strerror(errno)`

Comment: I did as you suggested

Answer (score 0):

Try writing the full path of the file in the remove function and in the new name in the rename function.
For example:

```
remove("C:\\Documents\\annuaire_client.txt");
rename("anuuaire1.txt","C:\\Documents\\annuaire_client.txt");
```

*Remember to use the \\ instead of \*